# Push array returning empty in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I would like to push value in `topicsVisited` array if this condition is true `if (totalPagesInSelectedTopic == this.state.topicPageNo + 1) {` and assign it value to the state. However in the `console.log(this.state.topicsVisited);` its returning empty array.

```
import {React, ReactDOM} from '../../../../build/react';

import SelectedTopicPageMarkup from './selected-topic-page-markup.jsx';
import NextPrevBtn from './next-prev-btn.jsx';

export default class SelectedTopicPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      topicPageNo: 0,
      total_selected_topic_pages: 1,
      topicsVisited: []
    };
  };
  navigateBack(topicPageNo) {
    if (this.state.topicPageNo > 0) {
      topicPageNo = this.state.topicPageNo - 1;
    } else {
      topicPageNo = 0;
    }
    this.setState({topicPageNo: topicPageNo});
  };
  navigateNext(totalPagesInSelectedTopic) {
    let topicPageNo;
    if (totalPagesInSelectedTopic > this.state.topicPageNo + 1) {
      topicPageNo = this.state.topicPageNo + 1;
    } else if (totalPagesInSelectedTopic == this.state.topicPageNo + 1) {
      this.props.setTopicClicked(false);

      let topicsVisited = this.state.topicsVisited;
      topicsVisited.push(this.props.topicsID);
      this.setState({topicsVisited: topicsVisited});
    } else {
      topicPageNo = this.state.topicPageNo;
    }
    this.setState({topicPageNo: topicPageNo});
  };
  render() {
    let topicsID = this.props.topicsID;
    let topicPageNo = this.state.topicPageNo;
    console.log(this.state.topicsVisited);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.topicPageData.filter(function(topicPage) {
          // if condition is true, item is not filtered out
          return topicPage.topic_no === topicsID;
        }).map(function(topicPage) {
          let totalPagesInSelectedTopic = topicPage.topic_pages.length;
          return (
            <div>
              <div>
                <SelectedTopicPageMarkup headline={topicPage.topic_pages[0].headline} key={topicPage.topic_no}>
                  {topicPage.topic_pages[topicPageNo].description}
                </SelectedTopicPageMarkup>
              </div>
              <div>
                <NextPrevBtn moveNext={this.navigateNext.bind(this, totalPagesInSelectedTopic)} key={topicPage.topic_no} moveBack={this.navigateBack.bind(this, topicPageNo)}/>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }.bind(this))}
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple exmaple for you.

```
increment(){
    let newCount = this.state.count + 1,
        right = this.state.rightElements,
        left = this.state.leftElements;
    newCount % 2 === 0 ? right.push(newCount) : left.push(newCount)

    this.setState({
      count: newCount,
      rightElements: right,
      leftElements: left,
    });
  }
```

The whole worked example you can find ***[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/272/)***

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I had actually tried it with simple example earlier and it worked properly. However, for some reason it not working in my case.

Comment: @RahulDagli could you create fiddle example?

Comment: I've been able to figure out the root cause. Since i'm unmounting `SelectedTopicPage` component from its parent component, when it reaches end of that topic page the state resets to its initial state.